# Get the count and total count joining 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have 2 tables in the MySQL database :

1.

```
p_code{
    code varchar(10) primary key,
    discount decimal(4,2) not null,
    valid_till date not null,
    daily int not null,
    total int non null,
    max_amount decimal (6, 2) not null
}
```

2.

```
p_user{
    code varchar(10) not null,
    email varchar(50) not null,
    date date not null,
    primary key (code, email, date),
    foreign key (code) references p_code(code)
}
```

now I want to get for a `code` in `p_code` total how many times an `email` has been used, total how many time the `email` has been used today and the details of the `code`.

I have tried the following query :

```
SELECT pc.discount, pc.valid, pc.daily, pc.total, pc.max_amount, c.tcount, c.count
FROM p_code AS pc
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT t.code, t.email, t.tcount, p.count
    FROM (

    SELECT code, email, COUNT( email ) AS tcount
    FROM p_user
    GROUP BY code, email
    ) AS t
    LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT code, email, COUNT( email ) AS count
    FROM p_user
    WHERE `date` = CURDATE( ) 
    GROUP BY code, email
    ) AS p ON ( t.code, t.email ) = ( p.code, p.email )

) AS c ON pc.code = c.code
WHERE c.email =  ?
AND pc.code =  ?
```

But the problem is that if I do not have any entry for the `code` and `email` in the table `p_user`, it does not return any row.

What I require that it should return all the columns from `p_code` and 0 and 0 for `tcount` and `count` columns.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, out the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you'll get regular inner join result.)

Comment: @jarlh do you mean to say that I should be removing the `where c.email = ?` ? and I I were to remove it where should I place it to get only the results for the given `email`?

Comment: Move `c.email = ?`  to the `ON` clause, i.e.  `...AS c ON pc.code = c.code
AND c.email =  ? WHERE pc.code =  ?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplifiy your query this way, and anyway you'll need to put the condition on the left joined data... in the left join.

```
SELECT 
   c.discount, 
   c.valid, 
   c.daily, 
   c.total, 
   c.max_amount, 
   count(u.email) as totalCount,
   sum(case when u.`date` = CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as dailyCount
FROM p_code c
LEFT JOIN p_user u on u.code = c.code and u.email = ?
WHERE c.code = ?
GROUP BY c.discount, c.valid, c.daily, c.total, c.max_amount
```

You could also do, for the "filter" on email :

```
WHERE c.code = ? and (u.email is null or u.email = ?)
```

Comment: This was a lovely solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.

> IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
>
> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2.

You need to modify your query like:

```
SELECT pc.discount
  , pc.valid
  , pc.daily
  , pc.total
  , pc.max
  , IFNULL(c.tcount, 0) AS tcount
  , IFNULL(c.count, 0) as count
FROM p_code AS pc
...
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But my query does not return any row if there is not entry of `email` in `p_user`. So even if I used your suggestion I would not get the desired result?

Comment: I see. I thought you are getting rows with NULL values.